# How to select two input fields with one radio button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

So what am trying to do is bind two inputs fields into one radio button for users to select. The values for input fields will be generated dynamic but present for selection with a single radio button. I tried doing it bootstrap but did not work.

```html
<!-- Twitter-Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">



<!-- Body -->
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" id="bind1" type="radio" name="name1" id="inlineRadio" value="valu1">
  <input class="form-check-input" id="bind2" type="radio" name="name2" id="inlineRadio" value="valu2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio">1</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" id="bind1" type="radio" name="name1" id="inlineRadio" value="val8">
  <input class="form-check-input" id="bind2" type="radio" name="name2" id="inlineRadio" value="val12">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio">2</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" id="bind1" type="radio" name="name1" id="inlineRadio" value="valu78">
  <input class="form-check-input" id="bind2" type="radio" name="name2" id="inlineRadio" value="890">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio">3</label>
</div>
```

Comment: an `id` must be unique. You cant use it multiple times. For that you must use `class`. Also please be more specific. I still have no idea what you are trying to do or achieve as final result.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I  understand, are you wanting the user to see just one radio button for each pair of 'inputs' so the user can select one or the other by clicking or unclicking the one radio button?

Answer (score 2):

you should add the same name for every 2 buttons to make them work as expected.

note: id should be unique in your HTML

```html
<!-- Twitter-Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">



<!-- Body -->
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="name1" value="valu1">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="name1" value="valu2">
  <label class="form-check-label" >1</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="name2" value="val8">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="name2" value="val12">
  <label class="form-check-label" >2</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="name3" value="valu78">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="name3" value="890">
  <label class="form-check-label" >3</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will cause all sibling radio buttons to be selected when one is selected.

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.form-check-inline input:first-child');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        // this.parent.querySelectorAll('input')
        var children = this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var j = 0; j < children.length; j++) {
            children[j].checked = true;
        }
    });
}
```

```css
.form-check-inline input[type="radio"]:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- Twitter-Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Body -->
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="name1" id="inlineRadio" value="valu1">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="name2" id="inlineRadio" value="valu2">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio">1</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="name1" id="inlineRadio" value="val8">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="name2" id="inlineRadio" value="val12">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio">2</label>
</div>
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="name1" id="inlineRadio" value="valu78">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="name2" id="inlineRadio" value="890">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio">3</label>
</div>
```